# Не работает crontab

Tags: linux, ubuntu, cron, crontab

Хочу добавить задачу в crontab на бекап базы данных (PostgreSQL).
Ввожу команду `crontab -e` и в конец документа прописываю:

`` @hourly pg_dump -d postgresql://user:password@localhost:5432/database > /root/database-backup/`date +"%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M"`_backup.sql ``

В итоге cron не срабатывает, хотя если написать эту команду вручную - всё работает.

Answer (score 0):

В итоге решил эту задачу вот так:

1) Создал скрипт:

```
USER='user'
PASSWORD='password'
DATABASE='bank'
OUTPUT_DIR='/root/database-backup'

DATABASE_LINK=postgresql://$USER:$PASSWORD@localhost:5432/$DATABASE
FILE=`date +"%Y-%m-%d"`_backup.sql

pg_dump --dbname $DATABASE_LINK | gzip > $OUTPUT_DIR/$FILE.gz
```

2) Добавил в crontab строку `@daily bash /usr/local/bin/database-backup.sh`.

Как я понял, ошибка заключалась в том, что команда crontab содержит символ '>', хотя он был необходим для команды, которую crontab должен выполнить.